# Django ModelForm ForeignKey query

Tags: python, django

I want to have a form which only offers the user to post a question for a project he is participating in.

models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Question(models.Model):           
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)


class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'project']
```

in views.py:

```
form = QuestionForm()
form.fields["project"].queryset = Project.objects.filter(project_name__in=request.user.profile.project.all())
```

But somehow the result of the query always stays empty.

Does somebody maybe have an idea what I am missing?

Comment: Post your forms.py code so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is over complicated. You should just use the user's projects directly:

```
form.fields["project"].queryset = request.user.profile.project.all())
```

Comment: Well, yes... Sometime it is hard to think simple. :D
If we remove the one ")" to much in the end, it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!